# I am getting a empty first page then a table is created after one page i am getting a footer page number

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, fpdf

I have tried printing a table in pdf after the logo but its getting a spacing after the header then footer.

Can someone help me out where is my mistake?

[image: screenshot]

```
from fpdf import FPDF
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(30, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

def create_table(df, filename):

    # Creating a page
    pdf = FPDF()
    pdf.set_auto_page_break(0)
    pdf = FPDF('P', 'mm', 'A4')
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.set_font("Times", "BU", size=20)
    pdf.image("logo.png", x=40, y=15)
    pdf.set_image_filter("DCTDecode")
    # pdf.set_auto_page_break(auto=1, margin=10)
    

    # Header
    header_text = "Saikasai"
    # pdf.cell(0, 0, txt=header_text, ln=True, align="C")
    pdf.cell(0, 0, txt=header_text, ln=True)
    pdf.cell(0, 10, txt= "", ln=True)
    pdf.cell(0, 10, txt= "", ln=True)
    pdf.cell(0, 10, txt= "", ln=True)
    pdf.set_font("Times", size=10)
    pdf.set_margins(10, 10, 10)


    # Cell dimensions
    cell_width = 30
    cell_height = 10

    # total width of the table
    table_width = len(df.columns) * cell_width
    

    # horizontal position to center the table
    x_centered = (pdf.w - table_width) / 2

    # vertical position to center the table (pdf.h - (len(df) + 1 ) * cell_height) / 2
    y_centered = (pdf.h - (len(df)) * cell_height) 

    pdf.set_fill_color(200, 220, 255)  # Light blue fill color
    pdf.set_text_color(0, 0, 0)  # Black text color
    pdf.set_draw_color(0, 0, 0)  # Black border color
    pdf.set_font("Times", "B", size=12)
    pdf.set_xy(x_centered, y_centered)
    for col_idx, col_name in enumerate(df.columns):
        pdf.cell(cell_width, cell_height, col_name, border=1, ln=False, fill=True, align="C")
    pdf.ln()

    # Loop through the DataFrame and print each row using itertuples() with cells
    pdf.set_font("Times", size=12)
    for row in df.itertuples():
        pdf.set_xy(x_centered, pdf.get_y())
        for col_value in row[1:]:
            pdf.cell(cell_width, cell_height, f"{col_value:.2f}", border=1, ln=False, align="C")
        pdf.ln()

    # Footer
    # pdf.set_y(-15)
    # pdf.cell(0, 10, txt="", align="R")
    # pdf.set_font("Arial", size=8)
    # pdf.cell(0, 10, f"Page {pdf.page_no()}/{{nb}}", align="C")
    def footer():
        pdf.set_y(-15)
        pdf.cell(0, 10, txt="", align="R")
        pdf.cell(0, 10, f"page{pdf.page_no()}/{{nb}}", align="R")
    # pdf.set_auto_page_break(auto=True, margin=10)
    footer()
    
    pdf.output(filename)
    
create_table(df, "Rough_2.pdf")
```

Comment: try changing you margins